# Why my node is invisible

Tags: sprite-kit, textures

I'm currently trying to make a node that can change it's texture, but it's not visible on the simulator. I know it's there, cause I set showNodesCount to true and it displays that 2 nodes are on scene. It's displaying a cannon node, but not rgyBox node, that should change it's texture if I tap on cannon node. Here is my code:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
var gameOver = false
let cannon = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "cannon")

let rgyArray = ["redBox", "greenBox", "yellowBox"]
var rgyBlock = SKSpriteNode()

func changeRgyColor() {
var randomRGY = Int(arc4random_uniform(3))
rgyBlock.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: rgyArray[randomRGY])
}


override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */
 cannon.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
 self.addChild(cannon)

 rgyBlock.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: rgyArray[1])
 rgyBlock.position = CGPointMake(self.cannon.position.x, self.cannon.position.y + 20)
 self.addChild(rgyBlock)
 rgyBlock.zPosition = 10

}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {      
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
     let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.cannon {
          changeRgyColor()
        }    
    }    
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check is everything okay with textures. Try to explicitly set cannon.zPosition to lower value than rgyBlock's zPosition.  Your code works fine when I try it...

Answer (score 0):

You need to recreate the `rgyBlock` by calling `rgyBlock = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: rgyArray[1])`.  Where it is defined at the top, it is defined as nothing.  You then need to recreate it in `didMoveToView`.  You can remove the texture set in `didMoveToView` for the `rgyBlock`.

You could do it a different way, and put `imageNamed: "aTextureNameHere"` into the define of `rgyBlock`.  This will give `rgyBlock` a value.  Then you can set the texture (as you already do) in `didMoveToView`.  This way may be quicker and easier.